# How i can reserve memory for bytes from python and read them one by one in nasmx64 assembly?

Tags: python, c, linux, assembly, nasm

I am struggling with very hard problem for me. I can't properly read bytes which I sent from python to nasmx64. my code is working with integers floats and other simple python objects but no with bytes. I am properly converting them with C language but i cant read them one by one.
Here is part of my assembly code:

```
SECTION         .bss

integer:        resb 4
string:         resb 8
bytes:          resq 1

SECTION                 .rodata

l_module_name           db "asm", 0    
parameter_list          db "S"
printf_format:          db "%i",10,0

SECTION                 .text

asm_bytes: 
    push  rbp
    push  rsi
    mov   rbp, rsp

    mov   rax, 1
    mov   rdi, 1
    mov   rsi, [rsi]
    mov   rdx, 1
    syscall

    pop   rsi

    mov   rdi, rsi  
    mov   rsi, parameter_list
    mov   rdx, bytes
    call    PyArg_ParseTuple WRT ..plt  ;;Here is conversion to C bytes

    ;;mov   rax, 1
    ;;mov   rdi, 1
    ;;mov   rsi, [rdx]
    ;;add   rsi, 48
    ;;mov   rdx, 1
    ;;syscall

    mov   rdi, printf_format    
    mov   rsi, [bytes]
    xor   rax, rax
    call  printf WRT ..plt    ;; Here is a try to print value of bytes[0]

    ;;mov   rdi, printf_format  
    ;;mov   rsi, [integer]
    ;;xor   rax, rax
    ;;call  printf WRT ..plt

    ;;mov   rdi, printf_format  
    ;;mov   rsi, rdx
    ;;xor   rax, rax
    ;;call  printf WRT ..plt

    mov   rax, Py_None
    inc   QWORD [rax + PyObject.ob_refcnt]

    pop   rbp
    ret
```

After compiling this and making visible for python I can use this function in python and here is fragment of python terminal code:

```
Python 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 19:07:31) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> string = "takie tam"
>>> arr = bytes(string, "utf-8")
>>> import asm
>>> asm.bytes(arr)
-1995689024
>>> arr[0]
116
```

As you can see I get some abstract values from this bytes.I also know that they are properly converted because I am not getting any exception in python while using this method. I don't know where this bytes are stored to properly read them.
I read also whole documentation for python C extensions but there is written that this converted value should be stored in "bytes" variable.
Please help me because I am loosing hope to make this work.
Yes and as I wrote earlier this is only part of my assembly code rest is purely about integration python with c and assembly.

Comment: Try adding `movzx esi, BYTE [rsi]` after `mov   rsi, [bytes]`. The result in `bytes` is a pointer, it seems like you are printing a (truncated) pointer?

Comment: Wow u are a god it actually works!!!! Thank you very much

Comment: And if I want to read next byte i should increment bytes?

Comment: Yes, or better increment `rsi` before `movzx ...` so that you never lose the original pointer (I don't know how python handles GC and the ownership of these buffers and you may still need `bytes` if you iterate over the buffer). Optionally, use an index register (eg: `movzx esi, BYTE [rsi+rbx]` or something)

Comment: Wow you helped me very much thank you once again